What is the easiest way to cut my cement basement floor for bathroom rough in?
I am cutting the concrete in my basement to add a bathroom. What cutting tool do I need?

How deep do you need it? :) You can also buy cement saws harbor freight or used FWIW... :)

You'll need a few things to make the job less of a hassle:

A portable diamond wet/dry saw from your local rental store is the ideal tool to make clean cuts through slabs up to about 5 inches thick (it looks like a chainsaw, but with about a 12" round blade). Gas-powered ones are fastest. With patience, electric models will also do. Note that both potentially create large amounts of masonry dust (depending on your use of water), so use a suitable mask. Also, the gas models obviously create combustion exhaust. A high rate of ventilating airflow is critical. Consider a respirator. These saws are heavy and create a lot of rotating energy when running. You need to be a fairly robust person to manage them. Use eye protection for all concrete work.

A sledge hammer and large demolition bar are critical. The saw separates the concrete, but it's still a chore to break it up and get it out of the channel. Rent or borrow these.

A rotary hammer with chisel bits can help in tight areas where the saw doesn't fit. It'll also let you clean up cut corners without having to overcut. This can also be rented.


